How can I add a new Live Template context?
For some reason, default Pest Live Templates included in PhpStorm (more precisely in the Pest plugin) allow it and test in Pest root context only. This means that inside a describe group, the Pest live templates do not work.
Is there any (easy) way to add a new context which does not limit the use of these templates to the root?
I'm aware that I can change the context and add PHP > Expression (it works), but it would allow the use of the template anywhere in any expression outside a Pest test file, which may produce an unintended behavior of the editor.
In my very specific case, I can obviously simply add PHP > Expression as applicable context for Pest live templates (I did, actually). But I like to consider the general case: if I were to have many templates (which I should), I wouldn't want to spoil the completion suggestions with irrelevant propositions.
Also, I consider the default Pest root context erroneous since it's not possible to use the templates everywhere we need them by default (it's explicitely unusable in expressions according to Pest plugin source code).
